# What does the message "hook_flag_access: ignore" mean, and how do I turn it off?

Tags: flags

I currently have the flag module enabled, and I have placed a simple flag on a node content type. The flag works fine, but I'm getting a Drupal message / notification in green that says "hook_flag_access: ignore" when the node is viewed.

It appears to be called by sites/all/modules/flag/tests/flagaccesstest/flagaccesstest.module

What does this message mean, and how can I fix / disable?

I'm using flag 7.x-3.1 on Drupal 7

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: This is probably bleeding through from the test suite for the Flag module. You should raise this on the module issue queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to disable the [flagaccesstest](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!flag!tests!flagaccesstest!flagaccesstest.module/7) module.

The problem is, in *flagaccesstest.info* the module declares

```
hidden = TRUE
```

So, it doesn't show up in Drupal module admin.

You could probably still disable it with [Drush](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/)

```
drush dis flagaccesstest
```

or even (last resort) SQL:

```
UPDATE system SET status = 0 WHERE name = 'flagaccesstest';
```

Alternatively, in flagaccesstest you could comment out

```
;hidden = TRUE
```

and then disable the module from Drupal module admin UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module to disable that "*hook_flag_access: ignore*" message. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Gives a site owner options to disable specific messages shown to end users. The core drupal message system as offered by drupal_set_message is an excellent way for modules to send out messages to the end users. However not all drupal site owners are keen to show all the messages sent out by drupal core and all modules to their users. This module gives site administrators a reasonably powerful way to filter out messages shown to the end users.

Some of its features are:

> - Filter out messages that match a full text string exactly.
> - Filter out messages that match a regular expression.
> - Permissions to specifically hide all messages of a given type from any role.
> - Disable all filtering for specific users.
> - Disable all filtering for specific paths.
> - Apply filtering only for specific paths.
> - Debug system to get messages in the HTML without showing it to the end users.

More specifically, you could use its "regular expressions" feature. But you have to make sure that you use a regular expression that "catches" the error message you want to intercept, as explained also in the [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1172266).

Below "*Tip: Keep it simple.*" on that page, there is a great sample.

So assume you want to suppress an error message containing this error:

> hook_flag_access: ignore

In this case a possible regular expression should look something like so:

```
.+hook_flag_access:.+ignore.+
```